# VMs can't ping each other

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, qemu, virt-manager

I have created two virtual machines in virt-manager. All machines (host & guests) run Ubuntu 14.04.

Host machine has two NICs. eth1 is used by host. Virtual Network Interface for each VM/guest is set to `Host device eth0: macvtap`.

- Host IP is 192.168.1.35
- Guest 1 IP is 192.168.1.41
- Guest 2 IP is 192.168.1.54

I can ping host from guest and guest from host. But guests are not reachable from each other. When I ping guest 2 from guest 1, output of `tcpdump` at host is:

```
17:55:11.631825 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.54 tell 192.168.1.41, length 28
17:55:12.631626 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.54 tell 192.168.1.41, length 28
17:55:13.632127 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.54 tell 192.168.1.41, length 28
...
```

Similarly, when I ping guest 1 from guest 2:

```
17:57:39.509281 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.41 tell 192.168.1.54, length 28
17:57:40.509280 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.41 tell 192.168.1.54, length 28
17:57:41.526726 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.41 tell 192.168.1.54, length 28
....
```

Both guests have following network configuration:

```
/etc/network/interfaces
    auto lo
        iface lo inet loopback
    auto eth1
        iface eth1 inet dhcp

route -n
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
    0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
    192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1       

iptables -L
    (nothing)

ifconfig (Guest 1)
    eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:ab:e6:fa  
              inet addr:192.168.1.41  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
              inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:feab:e6fa/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:728 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:638 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:817117 (817.1 KB)  TX bytes:51190 (51.1 KB)

    lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
              inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
              inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
              UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
              RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
              RX bytes:1184 (1.1 KB)  TX bytes:1184 (1.1 KB)
```

Host:

```
/etc/network/interfaces
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

route -n
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
    0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
    192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth1

iptables -L
    (nothing)

ifconfig
    eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:62:66:26:eb:d8  
              inet6 addr: fe80::a62:66ff:fe26:ebd8/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:218 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:110 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:67520 (67.5 KB)  TX bytes:20012 (20.0 KB)

    eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 70:62:b8:b5:2c:1b  
              inet addr:192.168.1.35  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
              inet6 addr: fe80::7262:b8ff:feb5:2c1b/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:4100 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:4678 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:1030310 (1.0 MB)  TX bytes:834427 (834.4 KB)

    lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
              inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
              inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
              UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
              RX packets:15192 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:15192 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
              RX bytes:1386699 (1.3 MB)  TX bytes:1386699 (1.3 MB)

    macvtap0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:db:29:6c  
              inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:fedb:296c/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:19 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:29 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
              RX bytes:2286 (2.2 KB)  TX bytes:5930 (5.9 KB)

    macvtap1  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:ab:e6:fa  
              inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:feab:e6fa/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:29 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:49 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
              RX bytes:4395 (4.3 KB)  TX bytes:7980 (7.9 KB)
```

Comment: For a good start - have you enabled ipv4 forwarding?  You can check it either this way:  cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward (0 is disabled, 1 enabled), or running the command: sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward

Comment: yes, ip4 forwarding is enabled (at host)

Comment: OK - can you provide us with more details about your network configuration on each of systems: hypervisor and both guests, please?

Comment: I added more info

Answer (score 1):

Replacing eth0 with a bridge interface solved the problem. But, there is another issue: 
[low-internet-speed-when-adding-bridge-interface](https://askubuntu.com/questions/656535/low-internet-speed-when-adding-bridge-interface)