# Low internet speed when adding bridge interface

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, virt-manager

I added a bridge interface using virt-manager.

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
bridge_ports eth0
bridge_fd 0
bridge_stp on

# eth1 is managed by NetworkManager 
# auto eth1
# iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

I use it to allow VMs get real IP addresses. But, it causes internet speed to get very low, even if VMs are turned off. How can I detect the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I enabled eth1 in /etc/network/interfaces (removed comments) and problem resolved. This prevents NetworkManager to manage eth1.

Comment: how or why would this free the logjam?